# Zeros in file for B200

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, software-defined-radio

I am using B200 to collect signals in FM band 96.5 MHz in a file using a File sink block.

When I am reading the values in the file, I find that the initial values are all zeros.

```
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        -0.01464888,  0.00244148, -0.01901303,  0.00729392, -0.03125095]
```

The parameters used are

```
      vector length :1
      unbuffered    :off
      append file   :overwrite
```

the code used is as this (I have modified the spectrum sensing code and added two lines as highlighted and deleted few unnecessary lines of codes)

[image]
Could anyone help why this is occurring? is it expected that the initial values will be zeros?

f=np.memmap("FM_Mar21a", dtype=np.float32) f[0:25] the output is as above. i used memmap because the file was really big with 1 billion samples and showing MemoryError.

Thankyou

Comment: can you post your whole flowgraph, and how you're reading the file?

Comment: `f=np.memmap("FM_Mar21a", dtype=np.float32)`                                       `f[0:25]`                                                                                                                          the output is as above. i used `memmap` because the file was really big with 1 billion samples and showing MemoryError.

Comment: I am not using any flowgraph but modifying the python code